# Let $D$ be a nonsingular diagonal matrix. Show that $1\notin spec(DA)$ if and only if $D - A$ is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $F = \mathbb{F}_3$ and let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $D =
> [d_{ij} ]\in\mathscr{M}_{n×n}(F)$ be a nonsingular diagonal matrix and let $A\in\mathscr{M}_{n×n}(F)$. Show that $1\notin\operatorname{spec}(DA)$ if and only if $D - A$ is nonsingular. (Exercise 674 from Golan, *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know*.)

$(\Rightarrow)$

I found that $I-DA$ is nonsingular but then I gent that $D^{-1}-A$ is nonsingular. I don't know how to use the fact that $D$ is diagonal to justify that $D-A$ is nonsingular.

I also know that $1\notin\operatorname{spec}((DA)^{-1})$

Thanks

Comment: $D$ may have to be a scalar multiple of identity...

Comment: what is the reason of that?

Comment: For $A$ and $D$ to commute...

Comment: I don't see why they commute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $D^{-1}=D$ since $F=\mathbb{F}_3$ and $D$ is diagonal.

Comment: I take it you solved the problem in the mean time.

Comment: I just realized of that.